# Limiting exponential regression in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have managed to create an exponential regression based on some data from an experiment. However, I would like the regression to stop when the y-values start plateauing (around x = 42000 seconds). See attached image of plot.

This is the code so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt;
import numpy as np;
import pandas as pd
import scipy.optimize as opt;

# This is the function we are trying to fit to the data.
def func(x, a, b, c):
     return a * b**x

dataC = pd.read_csv("yeastdata1cropped.txt")
data = pd.read_csv("yeastdata1.txt")

xdata = np.array(data.iloc[:,1])
ydata = np.array(data.iloc[:,0])

xdatac = np.array(dataC.iloc[:,1])
ydatac = np.array(dataC.iloc[:,0])

# Plot the actual data
plt.plot(xdata, ydata, ".", label="Data");

# The actual curve fitting happens here
optimizedParameters, pcov = opt.curve_fit(func, xdatac, ydatac);

# Use the optimized parameters to plot the best fit
plt.plot(xdata, func(xdata, *optimizedParameters), label="fit");

# Show the graph
plt.legend();
plt.show();
```

[image]

Comment: You can easily access data in pandas DataFrames with `xdata = data.iloc[:,1].values` instead of `xdata = np.array(data.iloc[:,1])`. Furthermore the parameter `c` in `func` is completely unused. And the parameters `a` and `b` are just multiplied. This **drastically** increases the complexity of the solution for the curve fitting algorithm. Instead you should just write `a**x`. This is basically the same equation, but with fewer parameters. Or did you mean something like `a**(b*x)`? Or including c: `c + a**(b*x)`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass the relevant/interested values to the fit as follows. You can use NumPy indexing to pass only those values of x which are below 42000. Using `[xdatac<42000]` will return the indices/positions where this condition holds `True`. The rest of the code remains the same.

```
optimizedParameters, pcov = opt.curve_fit(func, xdatac[xdatac<42000],
                                          ydatac[xdatac<42000]);
```

This way, the fit will only be performed up to 42000 and you can still plot the fitted line later by passing the complete x data.